# ESLint Error: Line number out of range

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm using ESLint with the Standard config.

I'm getting this error when running `eslint --fix */**`:

```
Line number out of range (line 318 requested, but only 317 lines present).
RangeError: Line number out of range (line 318 requested, but only 317 lines present).
    at SourceCode.getIndexFromLoc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/source-code.js:389:19)
    at Object.fix (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines.js:116:52)
    at RuleContext.report (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/rule-context.js:127:34)
    at Program:exit.allLines.reduce.concat.reduce (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines.js:108:37)
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at EventEmitter.Program:exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines.js:93:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelector (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:265:26)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelectors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:294:22)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

I tried `standard --fix` first from the Standard CLI and got the same error, and then tried it directly from ESLint to confirm that it was an error thrown by the latter, and not the former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8401.

> It appears that this error is consistently thrown if the file ends in a new line with a space character. When I delete the space, the error goes away.